# Trouble with IMovie?

Tags: iphone, imovie

My friend can get iMovie for free on his iPhone, but I can't. I still have to pay $4.99 for the app. I've asked 3 other friends about the app and all of them get it free. Why can't I get this app?

Comment: what is your iPhone model ? and is it on IOS8

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Apple says:

Feb 3, 2015 - To qualify for these free apps, you need a device that was activated or purchased on or after September 1, 2013.

When you upgrade to iOS 8 on a qualifying device or buy a new device with iOS 8, you'll have access to these apps for free: **iMovie**